# Why will my Insert statement not do anything using parameters from list boxes?

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, listbox

The SQL statement works just fine, but it does not work with the following code. Any help would be nice. I am trying to use data in two list boxes to pass to the parameters here.

```
string cs = "Data Source= $%^$# ;Initial Catalog=Blah;User ID=ID;Password=Pass";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
            cn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("if not exists (select companyid, reportdefid from companyreports with (nolock) where companyid = @companyid and reportdefid = @reportdefid) insert into companyreports (companyid, reportdefid, tab, listorder) values ( @companyid, @reportdefid, 999, 1)", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyid", listCompanytoAddto.Items); // need correct value here
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportdefid", listAddedReports.Items);

            MessageBox.Show("Update is complete");  
            cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could foreach through your listbox items until you find what you want, then throw that item in an object and pass that objects id.

```
CompanyClass myCompany = null;
foreach(CompanyClass item in listCompanytoAddTo.Items)
{
    if(item.someproperty == something.somePropertyYourLookingFor)
    {
        myCompany = item;
    }
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyid", myCompany.id);

Edit: Do that same code above basically but for your other listbox.
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not a DB pro, but can 'companyid' and 'reportdefid' accept multiple values?

```
listCompanytoAddto.Items
```

Will be an array of all the items in the list, where you may actually want just

```
listCompanytoAddto.SelectedItem.ToString()
```